# convergence radius of Pochhammer symbol series

Tags: cv.complex-variables

What is the convergence radius of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n z^{(n)}}{n!},$$
where $z^{(n)}$ is Pochhammer symbol?

Comment: I think we need $\textrm{Re}\, z<0$ for absolute convergence, from Stirling type approximations.

Comment: This is not a power series, so it doesn't have a radius of convergence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was founded on a misunderstanding

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n z^{(n)}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-z}n1^n.$$
Conditions for convergence of binomial series you can find in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Answer (score 1):

The Maple code

```
sum((-1)^n*pochhammer(z, n)/factorial(n), n = 0 .. infinity);
```

produces a closed-form expression $$\left( {2}^{z} \right) ^{-1}. $$

Comment: This is the FALLING Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: @IgorRivin: No, $2^{-z}$ is correct (for $\operatorname{Re}z<1$, where the series converges). This is immediate from Alexey Ustinov’s answer.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I am a bit confused, obviously...